# List all transformation/ aggregation in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have a long query with many transformations. I need to list all aggregation and transformation done within the query.

For example

```
select sum(a) as product,
sum(quantity) as salesprice,
productcode

from factSales
group by 
productcode
```

As result, I need

```
Transformation    column 
------------------------------------
sum(a)            product
sum(quantity)     salesprice
group by 
productcode       Regroupment
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: The query planner has that information, but I don't think it offers it to you clearly. Part of that could be seen by retrieving the execution plan, but not with the details you want.

Comment: The best descriptor of T-SQL transformations is.... T-SQL. I'm not sure what the objective of your result is but it won't tell you anything useful for a complex query with subtables, union all, joins etc Your result can be produced with any string searching algorithm (regular expressions might be one approach).